# filter size in convolution layers

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, layer

what happens if I add another convolution layer after convolution layer with the same filter size

for example, in a network of around 20 layers, I have to choose different filter sizes among convolution layers. so what will be the impact if  I do something like this

```
inner = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,2),strides=2,padding='valid', name ='max3')(inner)

inner = Conv2D(64, (3,3),strides=1,padding= 'same', name='conv6', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inner)
 
inner = Conv2D(64, (3,3),strides=1,padding= 'same', name='conv7', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inner)
 
inner = Conv2D(64, (3,3),strides=1,padding= 'same', name='conv8', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inner)  
inner = BatchNormalization()(inner)
```

Answer (score 1):

Trained with both scenarios where with same filters and different filters
(1) The observation is when trained with more weights(means more filters with increase in number) the test accuracy is more
(2) when trained with same filters the accuracy is not as good as earlier case.

Ran the below code on CIFAR10 dataset.

```
   model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
   model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
   model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
   model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
   model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
```

Total params: 56,320
Trainable params: 56,320
Non-trainable params: 0

in this case loss: 0.9110 - accuracy: 0.6937

```
   model = models.Sequential()
   model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
   model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
   model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
   model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
   model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
```

Total params: 19,392
Trainable params: 19,392
Non-trainable params: 0

in this case: loss: 0.9760  and accuracy: 0.6695